# Jquery Ajax Returned Array - how to handle in Javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

If someone could assist me please. I'm doing a jquery Ajax post, for some reason the Json object isn't working so just returning a php array instead

```
$.post
(  
  "classes/RegisterUser.php",  
  $("#frmRegistration").serialize(),  
  function(data)
  {  
   alert(data);  
  } 
);
```

The data is returned to Javascript 100% as

```
array
(
   [key]=>value
   [Name] => SomeOneName
   [Surname] => SomeOneSurName
)
```

How would i go about getting the value of Surname in Javascript?

Thanks for your assistance?
Regards

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on The MYYN's answer, after you get your script to return JSON, you must specify that you're receiving JSON and act accordingly. You can do this with `.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'classes/RegisterUser.php',
    data: $("#frmRegistration").serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(obj) {
        // This alerts SomeOneSurName
        alert(obj.Surname);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your PHP script *should* return json (right now it seem to return something like `var_dump($some_ary);`. A proper way to do this is via php's [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: I used the json_encode method which returns the databack 100%, when i then try to display the data in javascript as e.g.

 alert(data.Name);

I get the error undefined?